# Emacs mode for StringTemplate

Tags: emacs, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

Is there an Emacs mode available for the [StringTemplate Java template engine](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) ?

Comment: Haven't tried it myself but I see https://github.com/cburroughs/dotfiles/blob/master/emacs/site-lisp/stringtemplate-mode.el - might be for an older version of ST.

Comment: Tried it and added the *.stg extension as well to handle group files but it doesn't do much (at least with the ST4 files I tested it with): only different colouring of string literals inside quotes which are too few in any case.

Comment: I made a stringtemplate bundle for textmate you might be able to adapt for emacs. It's a bit ugly.. - hasn't been touched in 2 years. https://github.com/I82Much/StringTemplate-Textmate-Bundle